# função while usando System.Drawing.Printing não adiciona nada?

Tags: vb.net

Gostaria de ajuda sobre um relatório que estou criando via código...

Seguinte na parte de inserção de dados pegando de uma `datagridview` estou com problemas, quando utilizo o comando `While` na pagina `printPreview` aparece os dados buscados, porem quando lanço o comando para imprimi-lo nenhum dado é impresso, somente cabeçalho e rodapé.
Porem quando uso o comando `For` ele funciona perfeitamente, porem não consigo adicionar mais de 1 pagina por causa do `For`.

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pdoc.PrintPage
    'Margens
    Dim margemEsq As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
    Dim margemSup As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim margemDir As Single = e.MarginBounds.Right
    Dim margemInf As Single = e.MarginBounds.Bottom

    'Fontes
    Dim fonteTitulo As Font
    Dim fonteRodape As Font
    Dim fonteNormal As Font

    fonteTitulo = New Font("Verdana", 15, FontStyle.Bold)
    fonteRodape = New Font("Verdana", 8)
    fonteNormal = New Font("Verdana", 10)

    'Linhas
    Dim caneta As New Pen(Color.Black, 1)
    'e.Graphics.DrawLine(caneta, margemEsq, 60, margemDir, 60)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\" & "vb.gif"), 100, 68)
    'e.Graphics.DrawLine(caneta, margemEsq, 160, margemDir, 160)
    'e.Graphics.DrawString("Catálogo de Produtos", fonteTitulo, Brushes.Blue, margemEsq + 275, 80, New StringFormat())


    'impressão do titulo das colunas
    Dim fonteColuna As New Font("Arial", 16)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Código", fonteColuna, Brushes.Red, margemEsq, 140, New StringFormat())
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Produto", fonteColuna, Brushes.Red, margemEsq + 100, 140, New StringFormat())
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Preço", fonteColuna, Brushes.Red, margemEsq + 500, 140, New StringFormat())
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(caneta, margemEsq, 170, margemDir, 170)

    Dim linhasPorPagina = e.MarginBounds.Height / fonteNormal.GetHeight(e.Graphics) - 6
    Dim linhaAtual = 1
    ' While num < DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    ' ou
    'for num < DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    Dim posicaoDaLinha = margemSup + (linhaAtual * fonteNormal.GetHeight(e.Graphics) + 70)
    Dim strings As String = DataGridView1.Rows(num).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    e.Graphics.DrawString(strings, fonteNormal, Brushes.Black, margemEsq, posicaoDaLinha, New StringFormat())
    linhaAtual += 1
    '----------------------------
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(caneta, margemEsq, margemInf, margemDir, margemInf)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(System.DateTime.Now, fonteRodape, Brushes.Black, margemEsq, margemInf, New StringFormat())
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Pag. " & paginaAtual.ToString, fonteRodape, Brushes.Black, margemDir - 50, margemInf, New StringFormat())
    paginaAtual += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Tua pergunta está pouco clara e, também, só essas linhas de código não ajudam nada no entendimento. Você não precisa postar todo o fonte, mas precisa ser algo que dê pra entender o que você está fazendo.

Comment: Arrumei a pergunta por favor me ajude !!